# Office 365 Activations in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to get the office 365 activations for a user.  I can go into the office 365 admin center and see the devices a user has activated.  However, I cannot seem to find anywhere in the graph api where I can get at that data.  I can run the reports and get totals for how many activations a user has, but I need to get the actual device names.  Is this possible and what is the endpoint for it if it is?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible, you can however voice your interest in such a feature or support similar ones in the [Microsoft Graph Feature Request Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

You may still use the [Office 365 activations endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/office-365-activations-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0) to get details like [users who have activated Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getoffice365activationsuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0), the count of Office 365 activations on desktops and devices, etc.

Comment: Hello @Dave, are you still looking for further help on this question? If not, please mark this question as answered so that it can help others.